# On signature matching of Standard ML

Tags: types, matching, sml, signature

To my understanding, a `CANDIDATE` signature matches a `TARGET` signature if `CANDIDATE` is stronger than `TARGET`. Then if structure `some_structure` implements signature `CANDIDATE`, it implements signature `TARGET` too.

But according to page 155 of Robert Haper's [Programming in Standard ML](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/smlbook/book.pdf) (Version 1.2 of 11.02.11):

```
signature MERGEABLE_QUEUE =
  sig
    include QUEUE
    val merge : 'a queue * 'a queue -> 'a queue
  end
```

matches

```
signature MERGEABLE_INT_QUEUE =
  sig
    include QUEUE
    val merge : int queue * int queue -> int queue
  end
```

While in my opinion, it should be `MERGEABLE_INT_QUEUE` matches `MERGEABLE_QUEUE`. Because if `some_structure` implements `MERGEABLE_INT_QUEUE`, it implements `MERGEABLE_QUEUE` too.

What's wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a structure implements `MERGEABLE_QUEUE`, it provides a function that takes a pair of queues of *arbitrary* type (as long as the two queues have the same type as each other) and produces a new queue.  In particular, it can take two `int queue`s and produce another `int queue` (and so it implements `MERGEABLE_INT_QUEUE`), but it can also take two `bool queues` and produce a merged `bool queue`.  For any type `a'`, a structure impelementing `MERGEABLE_QUEUE` also implements the hypothetical `MERGEABLE_a'_QUEUE`.

The other way around is not true.  A structure implementing `MERGEABLE_INT_QUEUE` can only merge two `int queues`, not any two queues of arbitrary type.